# Instance of a modified dict class should return one of the values

Tags: python

I wonder if it is possible to create a Python class with following properties:

1. It should have all properties of the list or dict, i.e. inherited from one of them
2. When the instance is called it would return an element predefined by index or key

For example:

```
class A(dict):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self['a'] = 1
        self['b'] = 2

a = A('a')
```

and when instance `a` is called it would return `1` as defined by the key `'a'`. The original access through the keys should still be available.

The problem X:

I have a class `Fruits` that is inherited from `dict`. In `self` it can have several instances of class `Fruit`, however often there is only one instance. So when I am working with instance of `Fruits` I want to use methods and attributes of the that single instance as if they were attributes and methods of `A`:

```
class Fruit(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'apple'

class Fruits(dict):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.fruit_name = name
        self['apple'] = Fruit()

a = Fruits('apple')
```

I want `a.name` to return `'apple'`. I have the solution using `@property`:

```
class Fruits(dict):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.fruit_name = name
        self['apple'] = Fruit()
    @property
    def name(self):
        return self[self.fruit_name].name
```

but I am looking for something better...

Comment: That's not calling `a`, that's printing `a`. Calling `a` is `a()`.

Comment: `a` should also behave exactly as the instance under `a` key. In this case it should behave as `int`. May be calling is not the best wording, but just modifying `__str__` is not what I am looking for

Comment: It sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/135744). What is the big picture, what are you trying to do?

Comment: Indeed, it is XY problem. Sorry, should've stated the problem itself...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I've followed your question completely, but you can't call an instance directly; you can call a function within the instance. Now, since `a` is an instance of `dict`, you can access its keys -

```
In [9]: a['a']
Out[9]: 1
```

Or,

```
In [10]: a[a.name]
Out[10]: 1
```

You can implement the `__call__` method within `A`

```
class A(dict):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self['a'] = 1
        self['b'] = 2

    def __call__(self):
        return self[self.name]
```

Then,

```
In [24]: a = A('a')

In [25]: a()
Out[25]: 1
```

Is this along the lines of what you're looking for?

Comment: `__call__` is almost what I am looking for, but ideally I would want to use just `a`, without thinking of it as being a method

Comment: As a language construct, you call `a` with `a()`. When you just enter `a`, you aren't calling it.